# Determine Tables Referenced By Letters In Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that references a few tables. However, it refers to the tables with letters.

So let's say a column called `Name` is from the table `Users`, then the stored procedure may call the column name `U.Users`.

My question is, how do I get a list of all such mappings i.e all the letters that map to a table?

Comment: How many tables do you have in that procedure?Cant you simply look up the aliases?

Comment: Do you know about [table aliasing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are referring to table aliases, each distinct query can have their own "mapping".  These alias values are not specific to stored procedures.  Here is an example:

```
select
   a.col1, a.col2
   FROM YourTable1  a

select
    b.col1, b.col2
    from YourTable2           a
        inner join YourTable1 b on a.col1=b.col2
```

`YourTable1.col1` and `YourTable1.col2` are returned in both of the above queries, although they have the `"a"` alias in the first query and `"b"` alias in the second query. See this [Using Table Aliases.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In examples like above, people often use a table alias because is is quicker to write `a.col1` than `YourTable.col1`.  There is no way for anyone to know the aliases used in your stored procedure, you need to figure that out, look at these examples to help:

```
FROM YourTable  a
--   ^table     ^alias

FROM YourTable AS a
--   ^table       ^alias

FROM YourTable1             a
    INNER JOIN YourTable2   b ON a.col1=b.col1
    --         ^table       ^alias

FROM YourTable1             AS a
    INNER JOIN YourTable2   AS b ON a.col1=b.col1
    --         ^table          ^alias
```

Comment: Also, aliases should be logical. [You shouldn't need a decoder ring to figure out what table "a" refers to](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3.aspx).

Comment: Not only because it is quicker to write but sometimes (maybe even primarily) because it improves readability of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Each statement assigns its own aliases for the tables it uses, if at all. The same table used in different statements could be aliased differently (or not aliased). There cannot possibly be a single place to look up every table alias or a simple method to recover them from all the statements in your stored procedure or function or view etc.

Comment: (And the same alias could be used for different tables in different queries. Or in the same query - subqueries, CTEs, derived tables, etc.)